# Rails Application sending HTML responses instead of JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a standard rails application. I am trying to perform simple AJAX for adding an object. The code is code that I've used before so I'm hoping there is something I'm just doing wrong in this instance.

Anyway, I am trying to upload document using **carrierwave**.

My controller action looks like this:

***documents_controller***

```
def create
  @document = @user.documents.build(document_params)
  @document.user_id = @user.id
  @result = @document.save
  if @result
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { raise "submitted as html" }
    end
  else
    render :back
  end
end
```

My ***document.html.erb*** layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="backend">
  <head>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'documents' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= render 'shared/fonts'%>
    <%= render 'shared/css'%>

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And ***documents.js*** file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require validation
```

A test for JQuery on the ***documents/index.html.erb*** view.

```
<script>
  if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
  }else{
    alert("jQuery library is not found!");
  }
</script>
```

And lastly, the ***documents/create.js.erb*** file.

```
$('#document-table > tbody').append('<%= j render(@document) %>');
$('#document-table > tbody').append('<%= j render 'documents/share', document: @document %>');
$('#document-form')[0].reset()
$('#edit_document_<%= @document.id %>').submit();
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @document], html: {id: 'document-form', data: {remote: true}} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>

  <%= button_tag class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" do %>
    <i class="ico-file-upload2 text-white mr5"></i> Upload Document 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The document table and document form are ids I've given to those objects. I don't think there is anything irregular about any of this --- and it works on other sites, but when I click submit, the response is:

`Processing by DocumentsController#create as HTML`

Let me know if there is anything I could missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use :remote => true outside html option, try below one

> form_for [@user, @document], :remote => true, html: {id: 'document-form'} do |f| %>

Comment: Submit as HTML still.